# Character validation in C

Tags: c

I am having trouble with character validation in my program. The program fails on how isalpha() is used. To be more precise, it goes into an infinite loop if you input a letter character instead of a number... Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define TAB_SPACE_SIZE 8

int replaceTab(int numberOfTabs)
{
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < numberOfTabs; x++)
    {
        char tabSpace[TAB_SPACE_SIZE];
        char space = ' ';
        int i;
          for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
          {    
               tabSpace[i] = space;
               printf("%c", space);
          }
    }
}

int checkInput()
{
    int numberOfTabs;
    char response;
    char enter;
    printf("How many tabs am I to convert to spaces and print the output? ");
    scanf("%d", &numberOfTabs);
    if (numberOfTabs > 0)
    {
       replaceTab(numberOfTabs);
       system("pause");
       scanf("%c", &enter);
       printf("\nTry again? Yes(Y)/No(N)? ");
       scanf("%c", &response);
       printf("\n");
       switch (response)
       {
           case 'Y': checkInput();
                     break;
           case 'N': exit(0);
                     break;
           default: printf("\nEnter either Y or N.");
                    break;
       }
    }   
    else if (numberOfTabs == 0)
    {
       printf("The number of tabs cannot be zero. Press Enter to try again.");
       system("pause");
       checkInput();
    }
    else if isalpha(&numberOfTabs)
    {
       printf("You must enter a number. Press Enter to try again."); 
       system("pause");
       checkInput();
    } 
    else
    {
       printf("The number of tabs has to be a positive number. Press Enter to try again.");    
       system("pause");
       checkInput();                      
    }
    getchar();
    getchar();
}

int main()
{
    while (checkInput());
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `isalpha` doesn't take a pointer.

Comment: Why are you passing an address to `isalpha`? (`isalpha(&numberOfTabs)`)

Comment: Basically - the program goes into an infinite loop if you input a letter character instead of a number...

Comment: I was just guessing at that point. I am not sure how to properly use the isalpha function in the context of my little program...

Comment: `scanf("%d", &numberOfTabs);` is not consumeing letters.  A way out, use `fgets()/sscanf()`

Comment: @Asterix You're asking for [tag:c], don't you? Re-Tagged ..

Comment: Yes, this is C. I am doing one of the K&R exercises (1978 edition)...

Comment: @Asterix _'K&R exercises (**1978** edition)'_ Pretty old, but -hmmm- still valid ...

Comment: Never use `scanf()`, as there is no sane mechanism provided for error recovery after your user types the wrong thing, and the line buffering of `stdin` always adds confusion. Instead, read a line with `fgets()` and parse it from the buffer, using even `sscanf()` if you want. Even then, `sscanf()` is full of pitfalls and edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

Change input scheme

... and drop the incorrectly used `isalpha(&numberOfTabs)`

```
for (;;) {
  printf("How many tabs am I to convert to spaces and print the output? ");
  char buf[40];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    printf("We are done."); 
    return -1;
  }
  if (1 != sscanf(buf, &numberOfTabs)) {
    printf("You must enter a number. Try again."); 
    continue;
  }
  if (numberOfTabs <= 0) {
    printf("The number of tabs has to be a positive number. Try gain.");    
    continue;
  }
  else {
    break;  // I'd put this whole loop in a function and use return here.
  }
}
```

BTW: Where `scanf("%c",` is used, bet you want `scanf(" %c",` to consume leading whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Yours else if statement is missing paraentheses and if you get the address of numberOfTabs in the isalpha function, it be comparing whether or not the **address of numberOfTabs** is alpha or not.  You may want to change it to this:

```
else if (isalpha(numberOfTabs))
```

Regarding to your comment below, you can change it so you can check if the numberOfTabs is alpha right after your scanf:

```
scanf("%d", &numberOfTabs);
if (numberOfTabs > 0 && !isalpha(numberOfTabs))
{ ...
```

This is so that your loop in your replaceTab function won't loop x amount of times (depending on the character(s)) you inputed

Comment: I have tried that before with no luck. It compiles but if you enter a letter you end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: Ahh yes.  You actually can move the isalpha check into the earlier if statment that you have, if (numberOfTabs > 0), and change it to this.   if (numberOfTabs > 0 && !isalpha(numberOfTabs)), So right after you scan in a letter into the number of tab, it will stop it from calling the replaceTabs function.

Comment: I don't think that works... Also - I may have to account for pressing the Enter key which makes me think I need an array here. The solution proposed by chux uses an array...